# Deleting Xenserver Virtual Machine used for Template

Tags: windows, xenserver, snapshot, template

I created a custom Windows VM in **Xenserver 6.5**. I took a **snapshot** and used the snapshot to create a **template** that can be used for future reference. Is it possible to **delete** the VM I used to create the template or will that impact my ability to use the template?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, yeah, if there's a full-sized VM template, you can delete the original VM and a snapshot.

However, there's an article on Citrix DB, that confirms this info: https://docs.citrix.com/de-de/xencenter/6-1/xs-xc-vms-snapshots/xs-xc-vms-snapshots-newtemplate.html

Comment: Thank you for the information. I took a backup of the VM so I'll try deleting it and the snapshot and see what kind of impact it has on the template.